# Bash Scripts / Regex to convert multiline variable declarations to single statements

Tags: javascript, regex, bash

I have a bunch of javascript files that have multiline variable declarations:

```
var myVariable = true,
    myOtherVariable,
    myInterestingVariable = 0
```

What I need to do, is run through all of these files and update those instances to be single statements:

```
var myVariable = true
var myOtherVariable
var myInterestingVariable = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your files elsewhere first.
Name the perl script `revar` for example, and run it
giving it the list of filenames. It will edit
them in place (overwrite the files, no backup). Make sure you diff the before and after versions
to check only the changes you wanted are made.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# replace multiline var decl. meah on stackoverflow
use strict;
use Fcntl 'SEEK_SET';
# called to replace match
sub rep{
    $_ = shift;
    /^(\s*)/;
    my $indent = $1; # note indent of "  var ..."
    s/var\s*//;      # drop var so all line similar
    # add var on each line with or without comma
    s/\s*([^\n]+?),?\s*\n/${indent}var $1\n/g;
    return $_;
}
foreach my $file(@ARGV){
    open(F,"+<$file") or die;
    my $data = join('',<F>); # read whole file
    # match from var ..., to line not ending ","
    $data =~ s/^(\s*var(\s*[^\n]*,$)+\s*[^\n]*\n)/rep($1)/gem;
    truncate F,0;
    seek F,0,SEEK_SET;
    print F $data or die;
    close F or die;
}
```

For example,

```
find /tmp -name '*.js' -exec revar {} +
```

Comment: Thanks @meuh! I need to run this through each of files in a directory. Is there a way to do this and override the file with the new contents?

Comment: @mindwire22 I changed the perl script to accept a list of files.

Comment: Exactly what I was after!